# Подсказка при ошибке валидации

Tags: c#, wpf

Сделал валидацию самым простым способом на исключениях. Вот так:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

Подскажите как мне теперь сделать чтобы при исключении еще на TextBox-е подсказка с текстом исключения выводилась? Я имею ввиду обычный ToolTip, красным вроде оно и само его подсвечивает.

Comment: Ну в официальном примере вам прямо код написан: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (ищите раздел To customize cell validation feedback)

Comment: Ой что то я проморгал это, спасибо.